# Creating a function to handle generic types of data items and convert to list

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a function which has to create single items to a list. Currently is as follows:

```
public List<string> CreateList(string str)
{
  List<string> ls = new List<string>();
  ls.Add(str);
  return ls;
}
```

Is there any way to templatize this and make it to handle any data type ? Say something like:

```
public List<T> CreateList(Tstr)
{
  List<T> ls = new List<T>();
  ls.Add(str);
  return ls;
}
```

Comment: Other than adding a space in `Tstr` to make it `T str`, then making the method generic (i.e. `CreateList<T>`) what's wrong with the code you've got?

Comment: I missed making the method generic i.e. CreateList"<T>". Missed the parts in the quote. I thought the return type would be able to handle the generic. I was incorrect. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to specify the type of the method:

```
public List<T> CreateList<T>(T item)
{
  List<T> list = new List<T>{item};
  //or
  //list.Add(item);
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply using the [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)?

```
var list = new List<string>{ str };
```

So why reinventing the wheel if it's already available?

Comment: Why `List<T> ls = new List<T>();  ls.Add(str);` shouldn't work?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan it will work, both are valid. Though the author asks for a generic method, not for a collection initializer

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin: but OP is asking for something that's already available. Why reinventing the wheel? That's just makes it more difficult to understand your code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter may be he wants more logic in such a method, like validation, buisinness rules or anything else

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin: what prevents him from doing that validation where he creates the list via collection initializer?

Comment: @TimSchmelter if he wants to create a list of multiple types and wants to extract this logic and not duplicate it wherever he wants to create a list

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin: then provide a method or constructor to initialize this type and use that in `var list = new List<ComplexType>{ new ComplexType(...) }`. I really don't see any use cases for such a method.